# Autocompletion keeps history on the inputfield and sends multiple requests

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I have the following code:

```
     $("#city").on('change', function() {
         $("#keyword").autocomplete('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/formhandler/autocomplete', {
             width: 300,
             matchContains: true,
             extraParams: {
                 data: $("#city").val()
             }
          });
     });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<select id="city" name="">
<option selected value="">--Select a city--</option>
<option value="1">city1</option>
<option value="2">city2</option>                            
</select>
<input id="keyword" name="" type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width:300px;"/>
```

I want to autocomplete the keywords field according to the city selected, but the problem is  autocompletion sends multiple requests (it sends the latest city id along with the previous data selected). When I looked this up in firebug, the keyword field keeps the previuos history. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that the parentheses and braces in your JavaScript don't match. This is how it should be, notice the last two lines in particular:

```
$("#city").on('change', function() {
    $("#keyword").autocomplete('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/formhandler/autocomplete', {
        width: 300,
        matchContains: true,
        extraParams: {
            data: $("#city").val()
        }
    });
});
```

You have also misspelt *selected* in the first `option` tag: `selcted` should be `selected`

Comment: should autocomplete have semicolon or not?

Comment: Can you delete this answer please , its about editing the code

Comment: Please could you explain further? I know that it might not have exactly solved your issue, but I still think that it has added value? After all, you did incorporate my suggestions in your edited question... or am I totally missing the point here?

Comment: I'm only trying to help :) If anyone posts an answer the covers what I have and more, then I'm more than happy to remove my answer.